Why do i get a no dependency information available error when the dependecy is not in my POM?
I had a jconn4 dependecy in my POM file on apchenetbeans I removed it as i dont need it (it never worked either) but now when I run my project i get the error 'The POM for com.sybase:jconn4:jar:7.0 is missing, no dependency information available'. There are no dependencies, ive deleted the m2 file, the cache, not sure what else I can do?

somewhere you have either a dependency defined in your sub modules or having a transitive dependency on that... can be checked via mvn dependency:tree ...

Add the pom to your question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
